# Assigning an attribute id as well as assigning a value to input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

html code

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label-m">Product Name :</label>
   <div class="controls-m">
      <input id="input1tray040" class="span10 " type="text">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label-m">Available Qty :</label>
   <div class="controls-m">
      <input id="input2tray040" class="span10 " type="text">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label-m">Total Inward :</label>
   <div class="controls-m">
      <input id="input3tray040" class="span10 " type="text">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label-m">Total Sales :</label>
   <div class="controls-m">
      <input id="input4tray040" class="span10 " type="text">
   </div>
</div>


  Jquery
```

I am able to assign id to my input textbox ,but my problem is that i need to assign a value to the specified input text box while creating this div, How to achieve this.My jquery code what i have tried so far

```
$table.find('input[type="text"]').attr('id', function () {
    var idval = 'input' + ($(this).parent().parent().index() + 1) + $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    return idval;
});


var foo = 'input' + ($(this).parent().parent().index() + 1) + $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
var bar = foo.split("input")[1];

$tdid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
var mapid = '1' + $tdid + '';
var addid = '3' + $tdid + '';
var editid = '2' + $tdid + '';

if (bar == addid) {
    $("#" + foo + "").val(data.product_name);

} else if (bar == mapid) {
    //  $("#"+foo+"").val(data.map_name);
} else if (bar == editid) {
    $("#" + foo + "").val(data.edit_val);
}
```

Comment: .val() definitely works to set the value of an input. Consider making sure $("#"+foo) works, and that you actually enter one of the if conditions.

Comment: @KevinB m sure that $("#"+foo) works

Comment: Then continue with testing the if statement. Get down to the 1 singular line that isn't working.

Comment: @KevinB sure will let you know the result asap

Comment: @KevinB it gets assigned and vanishes off

Comment: Is your page reloading? that's what it sounds like.

Comment: if the page reloads then the id should also be vanished right but the id is set not the input value

Comment: if the value "vanishes", the value is either being cleared, the elemnt is being re-created, or the page is being reloaded. Which of those is it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33800/discussion-between-dude-and-kevin-b)

Comment: @KevinB then the attr id should also be cleared if that s the case right..but the attr id is assigned

Comment: The id wouldn't be cleared if you had something else clearing the value. Based on what you've expressed so far, the value shouldn't be getting lost. Please create a testable test-case so that we can see what is going on. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/MQjHN/ All i did was substitute in some code for what was missing from yours.

Comment: @kevinB but in my case the four div are been appended to table one after the other if it has one table row it works fine but when many rows are created it vanishes off